Getting Error "expected 0 constructor arguments, got 6"
While running the command yarn hardhat deploy it is giving me following error
Error: expected 0 constructor arguments, got 6
Deploy Script

        const {network} = require("hardhat");
        const{verify} = require("../utils/verify");
        const {developmentChains, networkConfig} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
        const {storeImages, storeTokenUriMetaData} = require("../utils/uploadToPinata");
        const fs = require("fs");
        const { networkInterfaces } = require("os");
        require("dotenv").config();

        const imagesLocation = "./images/randomNft";

        const metaDataTemplate = {
            name: "",
            description: "",
            image: "",
            attribute: [
                {
                trait_type: "Cuteness",
                value: 100,
                },
             ],
        };

        module.exports = async function({getNamedAccounts ,deployments}){
        const {deploy, log} = deployments;
        const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();
        const chainId = network.config.chainId;
        let tokenUris;
        if(process.env.UPLOAD_TO_PINATA === "true"){
        tokenUris = await handleTokenUris();
        }

        let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;

        if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)){
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock");
        const vrfCoordinatorV2 = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address);
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
        const tx = await vrfCoordinatorV2.createSubscription();
        const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1);

        subscriptionId = txReceipt.logs[0].args.subId;
    }else{
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId].vrfCoordinatorV2;
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId].subscriptionId;
    }

    log("-------------------");

    const args = [vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, networkConfig[chainId].gasLane, networkConfig[chainId].callbackGasLimit,  tokenUris,  networkConfig[chainId].mintFee];
    const randomIpfs = await deploy("RandomIpfsNft",{
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmation || 1,
    });

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, randomIpfs.address)
    }

    log("-----------------------------");
    
    if(!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHER_API){
        log("Verifying");
        await verify(randomIpfs.address, args);
    }

    }

        async function handleTokenUris() {
        tokenUris = [];

        const {responses: imageUploadResponses, files} =await storeImages(imagesLocation);

        for(const imageUploadResponsesIndex in imageUploadResponses){
        let tokenUriMetaData = { ...metaDataTemplate};
        tokenUriMetaData.name = files[imageUploadResponsesIndex].replace(".png", "");
        tokenUriMetaData.description = `An adorable ${tokenUriMetaData.name}`;
        tokenUriMetaData.image = `ipfs://${imageUploadResponses[imageUploadResponsesIndex].IpfsHash}`;
        console.log(`Uploding ${tokenUriMetaData.name}`);

        const metaDataUploadResponse = await storeTokenUriMetaData(tokenUriMetaData);
        tokenUris.push(`ipfs://${metaDataUploadResponse.IpfsHash}`);
    }
    console.log("Token Uris uploaded");
    console.log(tokenUris);
    return tokenUris;
    }

    module.exports.tags = ["all", "randomIpfs", "main"]

Soloidity Code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

error RandomIpfsNft__RangeOutOfBounds();
error RandomIpfsNft__NeedMoreETHSent();
error RandomIpfsNft__TransferFailed();

abstract contract RandomIpfsNft is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable{

    enum Breed {
        PUG,
        SHIB_INU,
        ST_BERNARD
    }

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private  immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATION = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    mapping (uint256 => address) public s_requestIdToSender;


    uint256 public s_tokenCounter;
    uint256 internal constant MAX_CHANCE_VALUE = 100;
    string[3] internal s_dogTokenUris;
    uint256 internal i_mintFee;

    event NftRequested(uint256 indexed requestId, address requester);
    event NftMinted(Breed dogBreed, address minter);

    constructor(address vrfCoordinatorV2, uint64 subscriptionId, bytes32 gasLane, uint32 callbackGasLimit, string[3] memory dogTokenUris, uint256 mintFee) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) ERC721("Random IPFS NFT", "RIN") {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_dogTokenUris = dogTokenUris;
        i_mintFee = mintFee;
    }

    function requestNft() public payable returns(uint256 requestId){
        if(msg.value < i_mintFee){
            revert RandomIpfsNft__NeedMoreETHSent();
        }
        requestId;
        requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(i_gasLane, i_subscriptionId, REQUEST_CONFIRMATION, i_callbackGasLimit, NUM_WORDS);
        s_requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;

        emit NftRequested(requestId, msg.sender);
    }
 
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override{
        address dogOwner = s_requestIdToSender[requestId];
        uint256 newTokenId = s_tokenCounter;

        uint256 moddedRng = randomWords[0] % MAX_CHANCE_VALUE;
        Breed dogBreed=getBreedFromModdedRng(moddedRng);
        _safeMint(dogOwner, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, s_dogTokenUris[uint256(dogBreed)]);
        emit NftMinted(dogBreed, dogOwner);
    }

    function withDraw() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 amount = address(this).balance;
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: amount}("");
        if(!success) {revert RandomIpfsNft__TransferFailed();}
    }

    function getBreedFromModdedRng(uint256 moddedRng) public pure returns(Breed){
        uint256 sum = 0;
        uint256[3] memory chanceArray = getChanceArray();
        for(uint256 i = 0; i< chanceArray.length; i++){
            if(moddedRng >= sum && moddedRng < sum + chanceArray[i]){
                return Breed(i);
            }
            sum += chanceArray[i];  
        }
        revert RandomIpfsNft__RangeOutOfBounds(); 
    }

    function getChanceArray() public pure returns(uint256[3] memory){
        return [10,30, MAX_CHANCE_VALUE];
    }

    function getMintFee() public view returns(uint256){
        return i_mintFee;
    }
    function getDogTokenUris(uint256 index) public view returns(string memory){
        return s_dogTokenUris[index];
    }
    function getTokenCounters() public view returns(uint256){
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
}


Your RandomIpfsNft contract is marked as abstract, therefore it cannot be deployed directly.
You need to remove the abstract keyword, i.e.,
Replace this:
abstract contract RandomIpfsNft is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

with:
contract RandomIpfsNft is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

Then, in your constructor, you should also pass the argument to the base constructor (i.e., Ownable) like:
constructor(address vrfCoordinatorV2, uint64 subscriptionId, bytes32 gasLane, uint32 callbackGasLimit, string[3] memory dogTokenUris, uint256 mintFee) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) ERC721("Random IPFS NFT", "RIN") Ownable(msg.sender) {


Done the following changes and now showing the following error            ``` TypeError: No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark "RandomIpfsNft" as abstract.
--> contracts/RandomIpfsNFT.sol:14:1:
|
14 | contract RandomIpfsNft is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable{
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Base constructor parameters:
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:38:16:
|
38 |     constructor(address initialOwner) {
|                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


I’ve added that to my answer. Please check.

What does that base constructor actually means over there?

Since the Ownable contract is being extended/inherited, so its constructor args need to be passed as well, the way you’re already passing for VRFConsumerBaseV2 and ERC721 contracts.
